# Как шаблонизировать эту форму в twig

Tags: php, twig

Подскажите пожалуйста как шаблонизировать такую форму в twig

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Бренд" name="brand" value="<?= isset($_GET['red_id']) ? $product['brand'] : ''; ?>">
        </td>    
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Cерия" name="series" value="<?= isset($_GET['red_id']) ? $product['series'] : ''; ?>">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Модель" name="model" value="<?= isset($_GET['red_id']) ? $product['model'] : ''; ?>">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="OK"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <table border='1'>
    <tr>
      <td>Бренд</td>
      <td>Серия</td>
      <td>Модель</td>
      <td>Удаление</td>
      <td>Редактирование</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
      $sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `ID`, `brand`, `series`, `model` FROM `technic`');
      while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo '<tr>' .
             "<td>{$result['brand']}</td>" .
             "<td>{$result['series']}</td>" .
             "<td>{$result['model']}</td>" .
             "<td><a href='?del_id={$result['ID']}'>Удалить</a></td>" .
             "<td><a href='?red_id={$result['ID']}'>Изменить</a></td>" .
             '</tr>';
      }
    ?>
  </table>
  <p><a href="?add=new">Добавить новый товар</a></p>
```

Comment: выкинуть из неё mysqli_query. остальное меняется обычным порядком

Comment: @Ипатьев, Можете показать какой то пример :)?

Comment: https://twig.symfony.com/

Answer (score 1):

.php

```
$sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `ID`, `brand`, `series`, `model` FROM `technic`');
$data = [];
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $data[] = $result;
}
echo $twig->render('demo.twig', [
    'result' => $data,
    'brand'=> $product['brand'] ?? '',
    'series'=> $product['series'] ?? '',
    'model'=> $product['model'] ?? '',
]);
```

.twig

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Бренд" name="brand" value="{{ brand }}">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Cерия" name="series" value="{{ series }}">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Модель" name="model" value="{{ model }}">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="OK"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Бренд</td>
        <td>Серия</td>
        <td>Модель</td>
        <td>Удаление</td>
        <td>Редактирование</td>
    </tr>
    {% for result in data %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ result.brand }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.series }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.model }}</td>
            <td><a href='?del_id={{ result.id }}'>Удалить</a></td>
            <td><a href='?red_id={{ result.id }}'>Изменить</a></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
<p><a href="?add=new">Добавить новый товар</a></p>
```